# Google pay-as-you-go prices

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-cloud-platform, payment

Google announced the pay-as-you-go for the usage of api keys.
You receive a monthly $200 credit.

What if one has multiple maps projects? Is this $200 per project or is it for the whole account (all projects combined)?

I can't seem to find the answer for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 200$ Given by Google for free is per Billing Account which you can use among all the projects linked to that Billing Account.

In Addition, let me remind you that using multiple Billing Accounts for a project is against Google terms if in doing so you circumvent fees.

Hope this clarifies your doubts